# adding a user to an existing group in linux

Tags: users, group

I am wondering if there is a difference between using usermod or groupmod to add a user to another existing group.
Example: we have a supplementary group named artists and want to add romeo to this group.

```
usermod -G artists romeo
groupmod -U romeo artists
```

I am using Redhat 9.

Comment: `usermod -aG artists romeo` For more information, `man usermod`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `man` page for `groupmod`:

```
The groupmod command modifies the definition of the specified GROUP
by modifying the appropriate entry in the group database.
```

There isn't a `-U` option (shadow-utils 4.6 of 04/18/2022).  The purpose of `groupmod` is to modify the characteristics of the group, not its members.

From the `man` page for `usermod`:

```
-G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
  A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of ...

  If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user
  will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be changed via the -a
  option, which appends the user to the current supplementary group list.
```

So, if your user `romeo` is already a member of group `paintworkers`, for example, then after:

```
usermod -G artists romeo
```

he will ONLY be a member of supplementary group `artists` and not of `paintworkers`.  If however you use:

```
usermod -aG artists romeo
```

he will be a member of both groups.

**Update:**

As mentioned above, this is true for `shadow-utils` 4.6 of 04/18/2022.  However the OP has pointed out that `shadow-utils` 4.9 of 12/02/2021 does now document `-U`:

```
       -U, --users
           A list of usernames to add as members of the group.
```

so presumably either the `usermod -aG` or the `groupmod -U` form should work equally well with the later version of `shadow-utils`.

Comment: tnx for the answer. I made a mistake in my question information. I'm using redhat 9 and there is a -U option for groupmod command. To clarify both commands are working fine for me. I am just wondering if there is a diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

... *seeing the forest through the trees*

everything you are referring to ends up simply happening in `/etc/group`

/etc/group  format

```
<groupname>:x:gid:user1,user2,user_n
```

x = password field, almost never used, would reference /etc/gshadow just like /etc/passwd references /etc/shadow.

gid = group id, a unique group id.  Convention is < 100 system stuff don't use, < 1000 for admin stuff, > 1000 whatever.  *don't quote me on this though*

for any groupname, simply add all user accounts to be in that group, separated by a comma.   I don't think I've ever used `usermod` or `groupmod` regarding what supplemental groups a user account is in, I just edit `/etc/group` directly is seems simpler, faster, easier to see exactly what all is going on.

Maybe the only point is there's a *primary group* for any given user account, which is specified by gid in `/etc/passwd` in column 4 for each account.  But all supplemental groups to which any user account is a member of are specified in `/etc/group` as to who is a member of what.  However you use `usermod` or `groupmod` ends up simply changing these things.

`usermod -G` will add a given user account name to the end of the list, in /etc/group for the group names specified.  If your adding one user to one new group, it's easier to just manually edit /etc/group otherwise for 5+ groups to do at one time this command might be a little faster than doing it manually in /etc/group.

`groupmod -U` I see as not a valid choice (in RHEL 7)

```
groupmod --help
Usage: groupmod [options] GROUP

Options:
  -g, --gid GID                 change the group ID to GID
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -n, --new-name NEW_GROUP      change the name to NEW_GROUP
  -o, --non-unique              allow to use a duplicate (non-unique) GID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       change the password to this (encrypted)
                            PASSWORD
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -P, --prefix PREFIX_DIR       prefix directory where are located the /etc/* files
```

Comment: To be honest, I usually edit directly, but it is not considered best practice, particularly for those new to the game.  Mess up the editing and you can cause trouble whereas the utilities guard against the sort of accidental slip someone unfamiliar might make.  They also take care of getting the relevant shadow files right.

Comment: tnx for the answer. I made a mistake in my question information. I'm using redhat 9 and there is a -U option for groupmod command. To clarify both commands are working fine for me. I am just wondering if there is a diffrence.